# MacOS Big Sur: Programmatically dismiss "Disk Not Ejected Properly" notification via Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, notifications

I do a lot of embedded software development. The microcontrollers have mini file systems that my programmer pushes new firmware onto the chip through.

Since I upgraded to Big Sur, I have been inundated with a **significant** number of Finder "Disk Not Ejected Properly" notifications every time I do the above.

Before Big Sur, these would vanish into Notification centre and I could clear them all. In Big Sur, I cannot.

I tried to record an Automator workflow to press the "close" button on the notifications, and this is fine until I try to run the workflow via Terminal where I get error:

```
The action “Watch Me Do” encountered an error: “This application must be allowed to control this computer using accessibility features, using the Security & Privacy preferences located in System Preferences, before using Watch Me Do”
```

I HAVE allowed these permissions, and tried executing with `sudo`, but no improvement. I then tried dragging the individual watch me do stages into its own stage to see the underlying AppleScript - as I am not so well versed with AppleScript, it didn't help me much.

There are a number of similar scripts online but they don't work with Big Sur from my testing,

Can anyone help me write an AppleScript that I can run via Terminal to help me dismiss these notifications?

They're driving me crazy and have to leave my Do Not Disturb on all day to hide this mess.

(1: to stress, these are not USB thumb drives or hard disks. These are microcontrollers so cannot be ejected due to the nature of firmware development)

[image]

Comment: Why not just eject the disks properly?

Comment: @Tetsujin the devices aren’t disks like a HDD or USB flash drive. They’re microcontrollers that have embedded file systems - this is what the programmer looks for to push my firmware onto. There’s no concept of ejecting these as the filesystem vanishes after firmware is programmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** and as an *executable shell script* in **Terminal**, under **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* saved as an *executable shell script* should do the trick. Note that limited testing was done and the *code* may need to be adjusted.

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "NotificationCenter"
        repeat while exists (UI elements of scroll area 1 of window 1)
            try
                perform (first action of group 1 of UI element 1 of ¬
                    scroll area 1 of windows where description is "Close")
            end try
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

**Notes:**

As coded, this should *click* the *close button* on all *notifications* until there are no *notifications* left. If you want to only target *notifications* with "DISK NOT EJECTED PROPERLY" then you'll need to modify the *code* to do so.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: After unexpected results, I learned that the way I was trying to run the AppleScript code was also incorrect. Subsequent attempts with the above code and by creating an executable script, I was able to close these notifications. Thank you very much!

Comment: I had to adapt the script to work into Monterey:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/467605/303345